# jquery smart banner ios 7 doesn't show

Tags: jquery, smartbanner

I have problem with jquery smart banner for ios 7.

I see smart banner on my website for ios app (from iphone), but when i click close it disappear which is ok.
But when i clear cache and cookies it still doesn't show.

Any solution for this? What to do to again show?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is using a cookie to store if you previously clicked on the close button.

You can clear it directly from the JavaScript console, by clicking on Resources/Cookies. Then right click and delete.

[image: Page cookie after clicking on the close button]